# How to read memory value at a specific location using VPI and verilator?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, verilator, vpi

I want to trace the memory value at specific locations during simulation of a hierarchical design using Verilator.  A short version of the memory model is defined as follows

```
`module tc_sram{

parameter int unsigned NumWords     = 32'd1024,

parameter int unsigned AddrWidth = (NumWords > 32'd1) ? $clog2(NumWords) : 32'd1,

parameter type         data_t    = logic [DataWidth-1:0],

}{

data_t sram [NumWords-1:0] /*verilator public*/;

}`
```

I want to use VPI interface in the design's C++ testbench to trace memory value at any location I want, meaning I provide the address of the memory location in the testbench, and the memory value at this location will return. Does  anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your memory model is not represented by a verilog code.
I am not familiar with vpi implementation in verilator.
However, using a standard vpi you can use `vpi_handle_by_index` to access memory elements.

I have an example below. First, some real **System Verilog** code:

```
module tc_sram #(
                 parameter int NumWords = 32'd8,
                 parameter int AddrWidth = (NumWords > 32'd1) ? $clog2(NumWords) : 32'd1,
                 parameter int DataWidth = 4,
                 parameter type data_t = logic [DataWidth-1:0]
                 )();
   data_t sram [NumWords-1:0] /*verilator public*/;
endmodule // tc_sram


module top;
   tc_sram sram();

   initial begin
      $testme(); // one of the possible ways to invoke vpi from verilog.
   end
endmodule // top
```

here is an example of vpi code which you can use as a base. It prints types of the variables. You would need to use `vip_get_value/vpi_get_value_array` and  `vpi_put_value/vpi_put_value_array` to read/write values to the memory.

The following example only uses `vpi_get_handle_by_index` to print types.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vpi_user.h>

void testme() {
    // get sram handle using instance path.
    vpiHandle arr = vpi_handle_by_name("top.sram.sram", 0);
    printf("sram: %s\n", vpi_get_str(vpiType, arr));


    // traverse array elements by index. You can use vpi_iterat/vpi_scan instead. 
    int indx = 0;
    vpiHandle el;
    while ( (el = vpi_handle_by_index(arr, indx)) ){
        printf("   el[%d]: %s\n", indx, vpi_get_str(vpiType, el));
        indx++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but for some reason I cannot even get a vpi handle. The hierarchy of the design is below and I add a warning hint if the handle doesn't exit. The warning always pops up meaning even the handle is not achieved :` vpiHandle vh1 = vpi_handle_by_name("TOP.ariane_testharness.i_sram.i_tc_sram_wrapper.i_tc_sram.sram", NULL);
      if (!vh1) vl_fatal(__FILE__, __LINE__, "ariane_testharness", "No handle found");`

Comment: Most likely it means that you did not specify a correct path. Unfortunately, without a reproducer no one can help you here.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Just to let you know I think the path is right. Because I once got the path wrong, and the error was different, saying something like "..... doesn't exist in the hierarchy" / "wrong path" or whatsoever, instead of "no handle found".

Comment: there could be something verilator specific, like missing compilation quals.

Comment: hi, just an update on this issue. It took me days to figure out the problem. Notwithstanding verilator does support accessing the memory, it creates a hierarchy that differs from the one that's instantiated by us in HDL. It just adds additional modules inbetween our HDL modules in some cases. So when we try to get a vpiHandle given the hierarchy we think it is, the path is just wrong, as mentioned  above, verilator creates a different hierarchy.